# MGTwitterEngine for Iphone Authentication xAuth oAuth

Tags: cocoa-touch, mgtwitterengine

All I am try to integrate twitter in Iphone application
As twiiter not allow the xAuth by default then How show I use it..
When will twitter approve xAuth for my application. As now it is in developing stage

**AND one more thing**

I have add the oAuthConsumer file in my application with MGTwitterEngine then how I call the oAuth.

Now I am calling like that

```
twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[twitterEngine setUsesSecureConnection:NO];
[twitterEngine setConsumerKey:consumerKey secret:consumerSecret];
[twitterEngine setUsername:username];
[twitterEngine getXAuthAccessTokenForUsername:username password:password];
```

But it is xAuth method

Please help me

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for oAuth I have use https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

and for xAuth we have to request twitter for it. and it is after releasing the application on Apple store